# Regular Expression for Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to pull a particular field from a postgres table that conforms to this pattern:

```
/^Untitled Deal \d+$/
```

For example:

> Untitled Deal 1
>
> Untitled Deal 2
>
> Untitled Deal 3

I have the query in postgres which is not working:

```
SELECT "name" FROM "deals" WHERE ("name" ILIKE '/^Untitled Deal \\d+$/');
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `~*` instead of `ILIKE`, if you want to pattern match against POSIX-style regular expressions.

I.e.:

```
SELECT "name" FROM "deals" WHERE ("name" ~* E'^Untitled Deal \\d+$');
```

#### See also:

- [PostgreSQL documentation on pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html)

Comment: `E` signifies that it is an [escape string constant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) (section 4.1.2.1), i.e. a string constant that allows you to do string escapes such as `\\ `.

Answer (score 2):

you simply can use `LIKE` and `%`

ie.,

```
SELECT name FROM deals WHERE name LIKE 'Untitled Deal %'
```

Comment: The number bit is important