# sql query for searching column name in database

Tags: sql, regex, database

I need to get all the column names from a particular database? and i would like to know how to use regular expression to get to a particular column in database.

Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: you could query for the table description and query for that might change based on the database you are using. once you have the table structure, run a string processing tool like `sed` `awk` on it to fetch the required details.

Comment: Your database will most likely have some sort of dictionary (table) where it keeps information about existing tables. Simply selecting the given column with names and using function such as regexp_like should suffice. Note, that this differs among the RDBMSs. Consult your DB documentation to find out where your specific DB stores such data.

Comment: This will get answer with this link i hope: [Answer from stack overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/sql-server-2008-find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you tell us which DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Comment: Why do you mention regular expressions in this context?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is ANSI, so it could be used with any SQL that supports ANSI.

Comment: @Doug_Ivison: in theory yes, but the individual implementations are quite different as well - and Oracle does not have it all.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to tell us which RDBMS you're using -- so we can give you ***more options*** -- but there is a way to do this that is intended to work with any RDBMS with ANSI SQL:  using `information_schema`.  (See ***[this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema)*** on information_schema, as an ANSI standard.)

To get all columns, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

To get a list for a *specific* column, when you know the exact name of the column you're looking for (for example `OrderNumber`), you could use:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'OrderNumber'
```

But if you don't know the exact name and ***exact case*** of the column, and if the `collation` of your database (or the column) might be case-sensitive... then you can match part of a column name using `LIKE`, and even include all results regardless of case-sensitivity by using the `UPPER` or `LOWER` functions.  If, for example, you wanted to see all columns that might be an order number, and you weren't sure if it was `OrderNo` or `OrderNumber` or `ORDER_ID`, you might use the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE '%ORDER%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME  --or by column_name, table_name, etc.
```

Also note:  the collation of your database may also affect whether `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` has to be upper case... some may work with `information_schema` (lower case), but some may not.

As far as using ***regular expressions*** goes... it goes back to knowing your RDBMS, and what you're developing (like are you trying to do the match in C# using RegEx?).  Within SQL, using `LIKE` is going to be easier (and there's ***[more here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)***, about wildcards with `LIKE`, in SQL Server), but for the record:  (1) T-SQL does not have support for regular expressions built in, but there are some resources listed in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635150/how-do-i-select-a-regex-match-from-a-text-varchar-in-ms-sql). (2) As a starting point in MySQL, look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732246/mysql-in-with-like/3732266#3732266), where it looks like you could use `<columnName> REGEXP <regExp>`, like `WHERE COLUMN_NAME REGEXP "*Order*"`.  (3) For PostGreSQL, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894034/regular-expression-for-postgres), from which it looks like `~*` in the `WHERE` clause will let you use RegEx, along the lines of `WHERE ("COLUMN_NAME" ~* E'*Order*')`.

If Regular Expressions are so important, that you're willing to create functions to use them, then (for SQL Server, anyway) check out these links ***[at Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19502/A-T-SQL-Regular-Expression-Library-for-SQL-Server)***, and ***[at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx#S2)***.

Hope that helps...