# Create table in HIVE with same columns as another table?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I want to create table from some metadata of another table in hive.  I'm using hive.

I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532419/sql-query-for-searching-column-name-in-database) question that the metatdata can be retrieved from the table by `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` in sql:

Does `HIVE` have a similar access to metadata of a table to allow me to create a table using the columns of another table?  Essentially, I'm copying a table without all of the tuples.

This is the best thing I have so far:

`create table <table_name>( (select <table_name>  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS)) row format delimited fields by '|';`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try `CTAS` syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name
AS
SELECT *
FROM old_table_name
WHERE 1 = 2;
```

Comment: For big data this is slower though, right?  it will still have to run through each row.

Comment: @Sother Look at `WHERE 1 = 2`. It is **always false** so you get empty table

Comment: but I don't think sql evaluates it that way.  I think it still checks every single row.

Comment: @Sother Did you try? The point the query optimizer is smart enougt to spot that it shouldn't go through all rows. Just check execution plan

Comment: @Sother Demo for you http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2a75/2/0 See execution plan: **`Impossible WHERE`** and start beliving :)

Comment: This solution will not result in a table with a partitioning scheme matching the original table.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `LIKE` so the new table gets the structure but not the data.

[Hive documentation](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hive/language_manual/data-manipulation-statements.html)

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
LIKE table2;
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know that this existed. This should be the correct answer. It's far more concise.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS schema.New_Table;    
CREATE TABLE New_Table    
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\034' LINES TERMINATED BY '\012'
STORED AS TEXTFILE location '/IC/New_Table'   
AS   
select *   
from Old_Table;
```

Comment: What does the '\034' do?

Comment: It specifies the delimiter. '\034' is the serde code for '\x1c' I believe. I think if you take out that portion it just defaults to the default delim. Add the where 1=2 if you don't want to bring in any data. Run the following to see what the old_table uses. "show create table Old_Table". This will display what the old table uses as it's delimiters and you can use those for your new table also.

Comment: also to prevent from going through each record do this: "select * from old_table limit 1;"